# Can someone please tell me the width of 32 ft long lvl i would need for a area of 12ftx 30 foot second level for storage only?

Tags: structural

Building a barndaminim at peak making a storage area of 12 ft wide and 32 ft long.  How wide and how many lvl boards do I need?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ... did you mean to say `barndominium`?

Comment: Usually depends on the weight above the floor.  A brunch of beach balls a lot less than heavy safes.

Comment: What are you storing? Hay, which is commonly stored in the upper levels of barns, is quite heavy, for instance.

Comment: @jsotola Sounds like a Mezzanine floor from the description?  And thank you for the new word.

Comment: You've got an answer from Lee Sam, who seems to be our best at supplying structural engineering questions, and you've got him stumped. I'd suggest you hire an actual SE to make the calculations for you. He'd be able to get every detail necessary, including on on-site inspection to ensure _other_ part of the structure are up to carrying the load (what are you going to use to _support_ this 32' beam?) and provide a legal sign-off that the calculations are accurate. Far cheaper than best-guessing it and being wrong.

Comment: I agree with @FreeMan about Lee Sam being our best at this. The actual SE would also have ideas on where you could get the beams needed locally.

Answer (score 4):

The Code requires a minimum of 40 lbs. per square foot (psf) for live load plus any dead load, which usually ends up about 10 psf for a total floor load of 50 psf.

The amount of load that is transferred to the beam is 6’ (half the total width) x 50 psf = 300 lbs. per linear foot (plf).

As you probably know, the beams come in different species and grades. Unfortunately the table only goes up to 20’ long… not 32’ as per your request.

I’d try a different layout with shorter spans.